# Changing sample format and bit depth on audio files with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, music

I recorded and mixed down a CD worth of homemade music with Ardour and stupidly exported all the songs in 48 kHz and 24 bit. Now I need it in 44,1 and 16 bit in order to have CDBaby take it and  give it over to iTunes, Spotify and whatnot. I expected they'd want mp3 for that but no.
I guess I'll be doing something like:

```
ffmpeg -i song.wav
```

and set the new sampling rate with:

```
-ar 44100
```

But how do I get the bitrate down to 16? I haven't been able to find any hints ... most of ffmpeg questions are about video and I get lost following first one possible thread and then another one.

Answer (score 13):

## Use the default

Default for WAV output is a 16-bit encoder (`pcm_s16le`), so all you need to do is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 44100 output.wav
```

## Or manually declare a 16-bit encoder

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 44100 output.wav
```

- See a list of encoders with `ffmpeg -encoders`
- See what audio sample formats (bit depth) an encoder supports with `ffmpeg -h encoder=pcm_s16le`

## Or manually set the audio sample format

With the `-sample_fmt` option.

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44100 output.wav
```

- See a list of audio sample formats (bit depth) with `ffmpeg -sample_fmts`

## Or use the [aformat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aformat)

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af "aformat=sample_fmts=s16:sample_rates=44100" output.wav
```

Comment: Ok thank you, too. I didn't know it'd turn out in 16 bit without having to specify. I'll be a lot smarter the next time around and export in 44,1 in the first place so no conversion will be necessary! I finished the job with LarsJoo's help yesterday and my music is awaiting scrutiny by CDBaby's team.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I was using ffmpeg to transcode from .aif to .wav, and splitting the stereo channels into separate files, and I noticed that if I used 24-bit .aif files, the output was only 16-bits. So I used this command: `ffmpeg -i $1 -c:a pcm_s24le -map_channel 0.0.0 ${1:r}-left.wav -c:a pcm_s24le -map_channel 0.0.1 ${1:r}-right.wav` which forced it to encode as 24-bit. Why isn't there an option to preserve the sample size when transcoding to .wav?

Comment: @PatrickBeard There is no such option because the user is expected to choose it like you did. Such an option would be very limited because not all output formats can support 24-bit.

Comment: Turns out sox can do this much more directly:

```sox $1 ${1:r}-left.wav remix 1```

This does the conversion without changing the sample size.

Answer (score 2):

Can this be related to Sample formats?

To see options: `ffmpeg -sample_fmts`

For you it will be something like,

`ffmpeg -i input -sample_fmt s16 -ar 44000 output`

Ref: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Audio-Options

Comment: Thank you sir! I couldn't find anything in the man pages ... it all seemed to be about video only. I can see now that I've got the right format so CDBaby's not accepting my files must have a different reason. Further digging is required but this direction seems solved now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that SoX might be a better tool for this job. I created a sample file with the sampling rate of 48.0 kHz and Bit depth of 24 bits, I have arrowed in the relevant sections:

```
andrew@ilium~/tmp$ mediainfo luckynight_48_24.wav 
General
Complete name                            : luckynight_48_24.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 16.6 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 2 304 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : 00000001-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 2 304 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz  <-----
Bit depth                                : 24 bits   <-----
Stream size                              : 16.6 MiB (100%)
```

Now I am no SoX master but the following command certainly converted the above file to a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz and Bit depth of 16 bits (as you have requested):

```
sox luckynight_48_24.wav -r 44100 -b 16 luckynight_44_16.wav
```

This accomplished the following, and again I have arrowed in the relevant sections:

```
andrew@ilium~/tmp$ mediainfo luckynight_44_16.wav 
General
Complete name                            : luckynight_44_16.wav
Format                                   : Wave
File size                                : 10.2 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 1 411 kb/s

Audio
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : 1
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 1 411.2 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz  <-----
Bit depth                                : 16 bits   <-----
Stream size                              : 10.2 MiB (100%)
```

And this is exactly what you are after :)

Comment: Thank you too! Back in the days when I started digital homerecording I used a format called "AVR" (from Audio Visual Research, IIRC) and tried numerous times to transfer the files to a current (as in not extinct) format and every desktop program that promised it would do it failed miserably. Then I discovered ffmpeg and because of the happiness I experienced I have been a true fan and user ever since!